# Distorted images when using the "download plot" function of matplotlib in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

when I am plotting a graph in jupyter with the code below, I can press "download plot" and get the expected png. However, when I use "pan" or "zoom" before downloading the plot, i get some distorted or even blank images like in the image below.

I am using Firefox 84.0, Jupyter 6.03 and Python 3.8.3.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Edit: I reinstalled Anaconda which updated Jupyter to 6.1.4. Now everything works as it should.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [4,2,7,15,17,11]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
```

The Distorted Image:
[image: Distorted image]

Comment: what happens if you call `display(fig)` in a separate cell (after you have done the panning / zooming)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the meantime I reinstalled anaconda which updated my jupyter version to 6.1.4. Now everything works as it shoud. I have not tested your idea before.

Comment: great, then perhaps answer your own question with the resolution in case someone else has the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Anaconda which updated Jupyter to 6.1.4. Now everything works as it should.